# On ESAPI Log Events

Tags: java, esapi

Hi can anyone help me as I am new to this concept as ESAPI has given 6 log events 
SECURITY_SUCCESS,
SECURITY_FAILURE,
SECURITY_AUDIT,
EVENT_SUCCESS,
EVENT_FAILURE,
EVENT_UNSPECIFIED

what these events do as I googled but I dint get anywhere please help me to understand this concept or suggest me some websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I didn't have the same problems finding the answer with google.  Did you read the [JavaDoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/Logger.html)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You  avgvstvs

Comment: But what does these events do? i.e. what's the difference if I log at EVENT_SUCCESS vs SECURITY_SUCCESS?

Comment: @Monir one will get logged with security-based log token and one won’t.  That way you can isolate sensitive from non-sensitive operations.  You could stream all security events to a separate log or just ‘grep’ on the tokens.